# Adding a pre-requisite task to mvn javadoc:javadoc

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I would like to run a shell script (to convert markdown to html) before `mvn javadoc:javadoc` is run.  How can I add this shell script as a dependency to the javadoc task?

Comment: If you're invoking this command from command line as a standalone goal, then I think it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using is just calling the goal javadoc but you need a life-cycle where you can attach the run of a shell script so you need to call **mvn site** to let your shell script run.